# Как можно создать уведомление ( не Push Notification, а что то вроде уведомления в Органайзере или Заметках )

Tags: android, уведомления, android-notification, android-alarm-manager

Доброго времени суток, кто знает как можно создать уведомление ( не Push Notification, а что то вроде уведомления в Органайзере или Заметках ), которое в указанное время всплывет и напомнит юзеру что то.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать стандартные уведомления Андроид https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Создание простого уведомления:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Готово. Теперь пользователь получит уведомление.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/141212)

Comment: Да. Добавил код для создания простого уведомления.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам будет интересно создавать напоминания в Google Calendar(Раз уж вы не хотите Push - уведомления).
https://github.com/vovaksenov99/Google_calendar_work
Вот например тут я объединил в класс работу с гугл календарем. Там не все доделано, но если нужно будет, то дооформляю документацию.